# JavaScript - document.getElementByID with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to code a simple game in an HTML document just for fun. In it, there is an image which adds to your score when clicked.

I created a simple `if` statement within the score-adding function which should change the image and what its `onClick` value is...

```
if (foo == 1) {
    document.getElementById("test").src = "images/test2.png";
    document.getElementById("test").onClick = "foo2()";
}
```

...but it doesn't work. The image will be successfully changed, but the actual onClick remains the same. Checking the console, it throws no errors, either.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `onclick` property is all lower-case, and accepts a *function*, not a string.

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = foo2;
```

See also [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Answer (score 19):

In JavaScript [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) are objects.

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(){
    prompt('Hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you might want to use "addEventListener"

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click',function ()
{
    foo2();
   }  );
```

Hope it's still useful for you

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = prepareButton;

function prepareButton()
{ 
   document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function()
   {
       alert('you clicked me');
   }
}

<input id="foo" value="Click Me!" type="button" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes JavaScript is not activated.
Try something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript"> <!--
      function jActivator() {
        document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
        document.getElementById("demo1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
        }
      function myFunction( s ) {
        document.getElementById("myresult").innerHTML = s;
        }
    // --> </script>
    <noscript>JavaScript deactivated.</noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="jActivator()">
    <ul>
      <li id="demo">Click me -&gt; onclick.</li>
      <li id="demo1">Click me -&gt; click event.</li>
      <li onclick="myFunction('YOU CLICKED ME!')">Click me calling function.</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myresult">&nbsp;</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you use the code inside a page, where no access to  is possible, remove  and  tags and try to use 'onload=()' in a picture inside the image tag '